# Incorrect encoding when inserting UTF-8 values into an SQL Server database using Perl DBI

Tags: sql-server, perl, encoding, sap-ase

I'll go mad about this encoding problem with Perl / DBI / Sybase / SQL Server.

My code example:

```
$Self->{DatabaseConnectionStr} = 'dbi:Sybase:server=myhostname.local;database=database1;language=german;charset=utf8;';
$Self->{DatabaseHandler} = DBI->connect($Self->{DatabaseConnectionStr}, 'srx', 'randompassword');

my $sth = $Self->{DatabaseHandler}->prepare("BEGIN TRANSACTION TRANS1");
my $rc = $sth->execute;


my $SQLStatement = " INSERT INTO [Random Table Name]                                       " .
                   " ( [Field_1], [Field_2], [Field_3], [Field_4], [Field_5], [Field_6],   " .
                   "   [Field_7], [Field_8], [Field_9], [Field_10] )                       " .
                   " VALUES                                                                " .
                   " ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)                                                " ;


$sth = $Self->{DatabaseHandler}->prepare($SQLStatement);

my @bind = ($F01, $F02, $F03, $F04, $F05, $F06, $F07, $F08, $F09, $F10);

for my $i (0 .. $#bind) {
    $bind[$i] = Encode::encode_utf8($bind[$i]);
}

$sth->execute(@bind);

if ($Success) {
    $sth = $Self->{DatabaseHandler}->prepare("COMMIT TRANSACTION TRANS1");
} else {
    $sth = $Self->{DatabaseHandler}->prepare("ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRANS1");
}

$rc = $sth->execute;
```

Why do I get values like "├╝berschreitung" in my database instead of "Überschreitung"?

If you need more information just let me know!

Unfortunately I don't know, what the encoding of the fields 1-10 is.

Comment: Where do `$F01` through `$F10` come from? The results look like double-encoding, but I can't account for the specific characters you're getting. It does seem likely, since that is exactly what you would get if you called `Encode::encode_utf8` on data that is *already* UTF-8-encoded.

Comment: _Where do $F01 through $F10 come from?_ - Variable. Mostly from another database (PostgreSQL).

Comment: _already UTF-8-encoded_ - Unfortunately, there is no difference if I remove that `Encode::encode_utf8`

Comment: The solution lies in following the encoding from the source of the data, so you must explain it carefully and include the relevant code. To simplify things, lets focus on whichever field contains `Überschreitung`

Comment: @Borodin: I found out, that the coding is "iso-8859-1" by printing the string into a text file. So, character 'ä' is hex E4 in iso-8859-1. After I convert it to utf-8, and print it to a file, the character is hex c3 a4 (correct!). But no matter what I bind to `execute`, the result is ALWAYS 2b f1. (Shown as '+ñ'). Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide the output of `sprintf('%v02X', $F01)` and of `Encode::is_utf8($F01)?1:0` (or of whichever `$Fxx` is giving you a problem)

Comment: @mstrd308: I think you should write some code that inserts a single record, including `Überschreitung` wherever it belongs. (You seem to be reticent to tell us, and I can't understand why.) It really isn't sufficient to say that you have these strings from various places and with unknown encoding, and one of them isn' being reencoded properly.

Comment: Hello, I already found the problem. My destination database runs with Code page 437 encoding. Thanks for your help. So I needed to convert my strings to cp 437 and everything is okay. Not very nice, but it's not my database, so I can't change :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SQL Server still to this day does not support UTF-8.